# Android set Listener for marker on google map

Tags: android, android-maps

This is the overlay class I am using in Google Maps. I added two markers to it and want to add a Listener to these markers. Below is my overlay class:

```
protected class MyLocationOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {


        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        // Converts lat/lng-Point to OUR coordinates on the screen.
        Point myScreenCoords = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, myScreenCoords);



        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.passenger_map);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, myScreenCoords.x, myScreenCoords.y, null);
        // canvas.drawText("I am here...", myScreenCoords.x, myScreenCoords.y, paint);

        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p1, myScreenCoords);
        Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.driver_map);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, myScreenCoords.x, myScreenCoords.y, null);
        // canvas.drawText(" Driver : I am here...", myScreenCoords.x, myScreenCoords.y, paint);
        return true;    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the ItemizedOverlay class for that to tap on the Marker. In that you need to override

> onTap() or onTouch()

which is used for marker as well as for map

```
public boolean onTap (final GeoPoint p, final MapView mapView){
boolean tapped = super.onTap(p, mapView);
if (tapped){            
    //do what you want to do when you hit an item           
}           
else{
    //do what you want to do when you DONT hit an item
    }                   
return true;
```

}

//You must have this method, even if it doesn't visibly do anything

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    return true;
}

here are the links

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

[OnTap() event on map is not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327622/ontap-event-on-map-is-not-fired/6327731#6327731)

[Android: ItemizedOverlay onTouchEvent and onTap overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971749/android-itemizedoverlay-ontouchevent-and-ontap-overlapping/5422563#5422563)

[Show popup above map marker in MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707923/show-popup-above-map-marker-in-mapview/3829582#3829582)